# forward slashes in shell variable

Tags: bash, shell, sh

i've a shell script to build a cURL URL and check the status.

```
    HOST_NAME=`hostname`
    PORT=`awk -F= '/SERVER_PORT/{print $2}' conf/mypros.properties`
    echo $HOST_NAME
    echo $PORT
    CURL_URL=http://$HOST_NAME:$PORT/api/vrtl/test
    echo $CURL_URL
```

it outputs

```
mytesthost
9993
/apisthost:9993
```

instead of

```
mytesthost
9993
http://mytesthost:9993/api/vrtl/test
```

When i chandeg it to:

`CURL_URL="http://$HOST_NAME:$PORT/api/vrtl/test" 
it gives: 
    mytesthost 
    9993 
    /api/vrtl/testost:9993`

the port number outputs correctly as below:

`[user@mytesthost]$ PORT=awk -F= '/SERVER_PORT/{print $2}' conf/myprops.properties [user@mytesthost]$ echo $PORT 9993`

```
$echo $0
bash
$cat 1.sh
HOST_NAME=mytesthost
PORT=awk -F= '/SERVER_PORT/{print $2}' conf/myprops.properties
echo $HOST_NAME
echo $PORT
CURL_URL="http://$HOST_NAME:$PORT/api/vrtl/test"
echo $CURL_URL

$./1.sh
mytesthost
9993
/api/vrtl/testost:9993
```

**ANSWER**

adding the tr command resolved the issue.

```
tr -d '\r' <conf/myprops.properties > conf/myprops_temp.properties
HOST_NAME=`hostname`
echo $HOST_NAME
PORT=`grep SERVER_PORT conf/myprops_temp.properties | cut -d= -f2`
echo $PORT
CURL_URL="http://$HOST_NAME:$PORT/api/vrtl/test"
```

Comment: How would it output "http://" and "mytesthost" when host_name is set to `"apishost"`. Assuming that's just a typo or two, just toss some quotes around that variable assignment: `CURL_URL="$HOST_NAME:$PORT/api/vrtl/test"` so there's no funny business.

Comment: It was a typo @JNevill. when I added quotes around them..

When i chandeg it to `CURL_URL="http://$HOST_NAME:$PORT/api/vrtl/test"`

it gives:

`mytesthost

9993

/api/vrtl/testost:9993

`

Comment: Are you certain PORT is returning value of 9993 ?

Comment: As an aside -- all-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the shell or operating system; [the relevant POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) reserves lower-case names for application use, guaranteeing that they won't impact system or shell behavior.

Comment: Yes @user 
Updated the question

Comment: btw, `set -x` (or `bash -x scriptname`) is your friend, re: debugging scripts that don't behave. If you [edit]ed the question to include that log from runtime (alongside exact/literal script text), it would likely be helpful.

Comment: OP, please post all the relevant details you added in the comments into your question.

Comment: `CURL_URL="http://$HOST_NAME:$PORT/api/vrtl/test"` where `HOST_NAME` is something like `"mytesthost"` and `PORT` is `"9993"` is spitting out `"mytesthost 9993 /api/vrtl/testost:9993"`. And you are in bash... I don't believe it. Either your variables aren't set to what you think they are or your computer is dyslexic.

Comment: `conf/myprops.properties` almost certainly uses DOS line endings, so that the value of `PORT` ends with a carriage return.

Comment: output of bash -x ./1.sh:

$bash -x ./1.sh

+ HOST_NAME=mytesthost

++ awk -F= '/SERVER_PORT/{print $2}' conf/myprops.properties

+ PORT=$'9993\r'

+ echo mytesthost

mytesthost

+ echo $'9993\r'

9993

+ CURL_URL=$'http://mytesthost:9993\r/api/vrtl/test'

+ echo $'http://mytesthost:9993\r/api/vrtl/test'

/api/vrtl/testost:9993

Comment: You have `\r` at the end of your variable name. Convert `conf/myprops.properties` to Unix file using `dos2unix` before you use it.

Comment: @anubhava i don't have dos2unix in my environment. How do I remove \r from the port?

Comment: Incidentally, this is literally the **very first thing** that the [StackOverflow `bash` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) tells you to check in the section "Before asking about problematic code".

Comment: @SandyR, if you open the file in vim and run `:set fileformat=unix` and then save it, that'll do the trick. Or you can `tr -d '\r' <infile >outfile`.

Comment: try it:
`HOST_NAME=$(hostname)

PORT=$(awk -F= '/SERVER_PORT/{print $2}' conf/mypros.properties)

CURL_URL="http://$HOST_NAME:$PORT/api/vrtl/test"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy tr -d '\r' <infile >outfile helped. Thanks.